# How Handle session using requestProcessor

Tags: java, servlets, struts, httpsession

I am working on struts,i want to know how to handle session using org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor
?
Where in have to check the existence of session throughout the app ?

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getSession();
```

In the handling methods of `RequestPostprocessor` you are supplied with an `HttpServletRequest` attribute. You can get the session from it.